# How to collect similar vectors efficiently with Python?

Tags: python, performance, group-by, coding-efficiency

I have a large set of 3-dimensional vectors, and each vector is associated with a weight. That is, the set is in the form

> {[[0.707,0.5,0.5],0.3],[[0.6,0.8,0],0.2]....}

I want to collect vectors which are closed to each other together, and sum their weights up. Now my idea is that: if a vector A is close to another one B, then I will treat them as the same vector and add the weight of A to the weight of B. And the Python code is

```
def gathervecs(vecs):
    gathers = []
    for vec in vecs: #in each vec, there are two elements, the first one is the normalized vector, and the second is the norm**2.
        index = 0
        for i,avec in enumerate(gathers):
            if sum(abs(vec[0] - avec[0])) < 10**(-10):
                (gathers[i])[1] = avec[1]+vec[1]
                index = 1
                break
                if index==0:
                gathers.append(vec)
                return gathers
```

But the time of this code is polynomial of the size of the original set. So, the question is how to design a more efficient algorithm?

PS: please generate the original set for testing the efficiency of the algorithm randomly.

Comment: Sample input and output will help others understand the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you're hitting the [k-means clustering problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering). This is a well-established NP-hard problem in CS, with many algorithms proposed to approximate a solution. You should take a look at those and try to adapt one to your specific use case. If you need more help with the algorithm, though, you should visit [CS.SE] - they are better suited to answering theoretical/algorithmic questions.